Is できる always the potential form of する (Nができる)?
I have recently learned about potential forms to express abilities and some doubts about できる emerged. The way I learned about it is as the potential form of する. So, it is clear that ことができる can be used to replace the potential form (e.g. 話すことができる instead of 話せる). When the verb is a する verb (I don't know a better term for verbs formed by noun+する, such as 勉強する) we may do many things:

勉強することができる (as discussed here), probably less common;
勉強できる;
勉強ができる;

As I understand, the first two correspond to the ことができる construct and the potential form of 勉強する, while the third one corresponds to 勉強をする (which is the usual business with or without を of する verbs (please confirm the sentence in bold font, I'm reasonably confident as the verb is する alone in this case).
This brings us to my question. If my interpretation that 勉強ができる appears when expressing the potential form of a phrase with (noun)をする, I wonder what happens going in the opposite direction.
Sometimes we find (noun)+ができる for nouns such that (noun)をする is not viable/used. The most famous example would be

日本語ができる。

Clearly, this does not come from 日本語をする and the meaning is clear. We would say that in English too: "I can do Japanese", but in English "to do Japanese" is used, as far as I know. As I understand it is more general than 話せる/話すことができる, as it also implies other abilities such as writing. So, what I do not understand is the grammatical role of this できる. Some suggest that in this usage this is not the potential form of する and should only be interpreted as "capable at" (cf. this answer).
Nonetheless, since I haven't found much about the aforementioned interpretation, I would be grateful if you confirmed/denied and/or expanded about it, possibly saying if this happens in many other cases similar to my example sentence.

Since できる is technically a different verb from する, and only sometimes used as replacement for される (spontaneous/passive/potential/honorific form of する, where potential usage is now archaic), it can have different range of usage. Can you maybe be clearer about what more information you need?

You can also read this, but I do not know if it answers your doubts.

For what it's worth, to my intuition something like “料理ができる” can also imply “is good at cooking” whereas “料理できる” is more so “can cook” as in a more transient potential sense like “I can't cook in this mess”. I think the “〜ができる” sense has an added possible interpretation of “is good at” but I feel someone with better intuition than I should answer that.


Is できる always the potential form of する (Nができる)?

No.  できる also carries multiple definitions such as something being done/complete, something being formed/created, etc.


準備ができました　→　I'm ready ("The preparations are complete")
都心に新しい公園ができるようです　→　It appears a new park will be built downtown



Probably the title of the question is not enough but in the body I explained that the context is still that of "being able to" and focused on a specific type of sentence.
